# Jquery delayed css div position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make my menu bar partially hide after a timeout of about 5 seconds of inactivity. The menu is positioned 20px from the top of the page and the basic idea is that a small section of the menu will still be visible once it has moved up to allow the user to hover over this for it to drop down again (hopefully this makes sense!).

I have managed the animation side but not quite the timeout.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have a delay function. However, you can use a sneaky and not-too-dirty hack to simulate a delay, by animating the opacity of an element from 1 to 1:

```
$('#visibleElement')               // Assuming the element is already shown
  .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000);  // do nothing for 3 seconds
```

So to slide up your menu 5 seconds after the mouse leaves you could do the following:

```
$('#menuDiv').mouseout(function(){
  .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000)
  .animate( slide up etc...
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this hide the menu after 5 seconds without regard to inactivity? As far as I got the question, it was more to the logic about setting timeout starting from inactivity...

Comment: Fair point. Edited my example to be on mouseout instead of pageload.

Comment: the opacity hack has seemed to work fine, it gives me the 5 seconds of position i want before the menu animates upwards, nice one!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `mouseout` event of the `div` that represents the menu to implement a function like this:

```
var waitingForMenuToHide = false;

function myOnMouseOut() {
    waitingForMenuToHide = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (waitingForMenuToHide) {
            // Hide the menu div...
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

and the `mouseover` event to reset the `waitingForMenuToHide` variable:

```
function myMouseOver() {
    waitingForMenuToHide = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at HoverIntent. 
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

This makes it quite easy to perform actions a delay after the user has stopped interacting with your menu.

Answer (score 1):

On the mouseout event start a timeout with the callback to scroll the element up. On the mousover event, if there is a timeout, kill it using:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

So it will be something like:

```
var timer;
$('mybar').mouseover(function(){clearTimeout(timer);/* Animate down code here */});
$('mybar').mouseout(function(){timer=setTimeout(function(){/* Animate up Code Here */}, 5000);});
```